Calling flow from lwc - Output is null
I start a flow from a lwc. It should return the ID of a record, but when I get the value in my lwc it is null.
The flow is called like this
<lightning-flow
    flow-api-name={flowApiName}
    flow-input-variables={inputVariables}
    onstatuschange={handleFlowStatusChange}>
</lightning-flow>

The flow starts as expected, with the correct input variables.
This is the output variable.

When I debug my flow I can see that the output variable is set. And yes, the variable is available for output.
I have used this guide to implement the function in my lwc js controller.
Mine looks like this
handleFlowStatusChange(event){
    console.log('handleFlowStatusChange');
    console.log('Event status:',event.detail.status);
    if (event.detail.status === "STARTED") {
        this.showSpinner = false;
    }

    if (event.detail.status === "FINISHED") {
        const outputVariables = event.detail.outputVariables;
        for (let i = 0; i < outputVariables.length; i++) {
            const outputVar = outputVariables[i];
            console.log(outputVariables);
            console.log("outputVar.name:", outputVar.name);
            console.log("outputVar.value:", outputVar.value);
        }
    }
}

The array that is returned in outputVariables looks like this
{
    "dataType": "STRING",
    "name": "varName",
    "isCollection": false,
    "flowName": "flowName",
    "value": null,
    "objectType": null
}

If I set a default value on the output variable it is set in the output from the flow
{
    "dataType": "STRING",
    "name": "varName",
    "isCollection": false,
    "flowName": "flowName",
    "value": "This_is_not_an_Id",
    "objectType": null
}

What am I missing here?

Can you please include some information about your flow, the variable you set-up and the HTML code where you include the lightning-flow? From the above information, it is hard to say what you are missing, as the value is clearly stated as null in the outputVariables and we don't have much info about it.

@prem22 added more info. I hope this makes the problem clearer.

Talked with SF support. The problem was in the (screen) flows.
I found the record ID in a subflow, returned it to the main flow, set the output of the subflow to my output variable, and then ended the main flow without doing anything else.
This is causes the output variable to remain unset.
One solution was to add a screen before the flow ended.
I could not replace the screen with a Get Records action or a formula.
My solution was to move the subflow in to the main flow. This also solved the problem.
